# Bootloop Sony Tablet S

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot-loop, tablet

I had a problem with my Sony Tablet S (Android 4.03) i tried to unnistalled some app and then alot of messages pop up one after another teeling that "x" application has fail, so i try to reboot, but since the tablet get stuck on the loading screen when try to initialize.

Anyone can help me to solve it without lost all the apps and info? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info), which includes some first-aid on the issue? If so, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Izzy thanks, yes i have seen it, and also i could fix the bootloop (just did a reset to factory) i couldn't save the data, but at least i can use the tablet again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dmitry. Would you mind making your experience an answer, including the steps you've taken? That could help future visitors (even more if you include links to where you picked details from ;) Thanks!